Leaflet control radio does not remain disabled
I am using JavaScript to add disabled=disabled attributes to the .leaflet-control-layers-selector radio inputs.
The disabled attribute remains on the inputs until the user hovers over the .leaflet-control-layers-toggle anchor at which point the disabled attribute disappears.
Is there a more Leaflet-y approach to disabling the base maps or should I try a different approach (such as an event listener on .leaflet-control-layers-toggle to add the attributes then instead)?

I don't know if it's a 'proper' Leaflet-y approach, but you can disable the layer by making the zoom property of the map smaller than the minZoom layer option or greater than the maxZoom layer option. In simple terms, setting the maxZoom to a negative number should do the trick.
